# Adding OCMock to Xcode will not link at runtime

Tags: xcode, xcode5, ocmock, xctest

I'm trying to get a basic app mac app running with XCTest and OCMock. But I am getting linking errors at runtime, I have several plain XCTests that run just fine, but the OCMock test is not working (other test hidden for brevity):

```
#import <OCMock/OCMock.h>

- (void)testLoadingInvalidSettingsThrowsAnError
{
    id harkMock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[Hark class]];
    [[[harkMock stub] andReturn:@"bla"] getSettingsAsRawJson];
    XCTAssertThrowsSpecificNamed([harkMock loadSettings], NSException, @"InvalidJson");
}
```

The error received at runtime:

```
2014-02-21 11:02:47.929 Hark[90819:303] Error loading /Users/chancee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hark-bsndafsdxydbivhhuuuyelepegkp/Build/Products/Debug/HarkTests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/HarkTests:  dlopen(/Users/chancee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hark-bsndafsdxydbivhhuuuyelepegkp/Build/Products/Debug/HarkTests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/HarkTests, 262): Library not loaded: @rpath/OCMock.framework/Versions/A/OCMock
  Referenced from: /Users/chancee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hark-bsndafsdxydbivhhuuuyelepegkp/Build/Products/Debug/HarkTests.xctest/Contents/MacOS/HarkTests
  Reason: image not found
```

What I've done:

1. Download the latest `OCMock.framework` and placed it into `/Library/Frameworks`
2. For my `HarkTests` target in Xcode I have added OCMock in the "Link Binary With Libraries" - however it does not show up in the list of available frameworks, I have to manually navigate to it. This raises a red flag for me, but I don't know why Xcode doesn't recognise it.
3. Compiles fine. But throws the above error at runtime (so no tests run).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic for finding frameworks at compile time is different from the logic for finding the framework at runtime. OCMock uses the `@rpath` mechanism. I would have thought that `/Library/Frameworks` is on the path by default. That doesn't seem to be the case. You could try to set the `Runpath Search Paths` build setting to include the directory into which you have installed OCMock.

Comment: Thanks. That was it. I had to add `/Library/Frameworks` to the Runtime Search Path. But thats so weird that it doesn't have that in there by default...